# Convert string to its lower case ascii hexadecimal representation

Tags: c#, character-encoding, byte, sha256

I'm creating a sha-256 hash for a payment integration
The requirements are (from the bank's instructions) :

Step 1: Create the string
eg 987654321012013:07:16-09:57:081.00826TopSecret

Step 2: Convert the created string to its ascii hexadecimal representation
eg 3938373635343332313031323031333a30373a31362d30393a35373a3038312e3030383236546f70536563726574

Step 3: generate sha-256 hash of the converted string
eg 3d7e75aa0b4e0e1d4a7ac87e451e64692cced46f4358ef35a69d96721341243c

The problem:
Step 2 in my code gives upper-case A,D,E,F etc which then produces a different sha-256 to the given example.  I need to produce the byte array with lower case hex representation.

here is my code (in .NET 4.5.2):

```
string hash = createHash( inputstring );

public static string createHash(string inputString)
{
      SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);
      // need my bytes to be lower case
      byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
      return GetStringFromHash(hash).ToLower();
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is wrong with `.ToLower()` for your input data too?

Comment: What? At which point did you convert `bytes` to a string` ? A `byte` doesn't have an upper or lower case anything; it's a number in the computer's memory.

Comment: Also, you did not convert the string to a hexadecimal representation (which would be a string again).

Comment: @Llama because the input string is case sensitive, the issue is the intermediate step needs to be in lower case
Caius - thank you, I realise that, my issue was with the representation of that number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing step is the conversion to a string in hexadecimal representation. We can convert the characters of the string to an `int` and then format it as hexadecimal with `.ToString("x2")`.

```cs
//Step 1: Create the string
string secret = "987654321012013:07:16-09:57:081.00826TopSecret";

//Step 2: Convert the created string to its ascii hexadecimal representation
string hexString = String.Concat(secret.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x2")));
// Has already lower case hex digits here. No action required.

//Step 3: generate sha-256 hash of the converted string
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexString);
SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);

// Return the hash bytes as hexadecimal string
return GetStringFromHash(hash);
```

Note that a string is an enumeration of characters. I.e., the [String Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) implements `IEnumerable<char>`. Therefore, we can use LINQ `Select` to convert the characters of the input string. Note that in C# the `char` type is considered to be a 16 bit numeric type. Therefore you can convert it from and to `int` (32-bit).

---

You can implement `GetStringFromHash` like this:

```cs
private static string GetStringFromHash(byte[] hash)
{
    return String.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}
```

Note that `.ToString("x2")` generates lower case hexadecimal digits. So, no further `.ToLower()` is required.

---

Note that the requirement of using ASCII restricts the character set to the range `(char)1 .. (char)127`. `(char)0` is excluded, because it can be misinterpreted as string terminator in certain APIs. So, it is not sure, whether this restriction concerns the secret input string or the hex string or both. It might be sufficient to limit the secret string to the range `(char)1 .. (char)255`, which would include some diacritics, but would certainly exclude Chinese character for example.

Answer (score 1):

You've hashed this:

> 987654321012013:07:16-09:57:081.00826TopSecret

Not the *ascii hexadecimal representation* of it

---

I suspect you want to replace

```
// need my bytes to be lower case
```

With something like

```
var inputToHash = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-","").ToLower();
```

Or perhaps something like

```
var inputToHash = string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
```

And then hash `inputToHash` (GetBytes it again), not `bytes`

---

If you need this to be higher performance, perhaps use a stringbuilder rather than bitconverter or linq